# Bootstrap Dropdown toggle doesn't work when called from an event handler

Tags: jquery, twitter-bootstrap, drop-down-menu

I have an  element, dropdown, and some jquery to toggle the dropdown dynamically. However, the toggle doesn't work when called from the event handler. I've already tried everything suggested by related Stackoverflow answers, but nothing works :(

**JavaScript:**

```
$(function(){
  //$(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown('toggle'); // this works
  $('#click').click(function(){
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown('toggle'); // this doesn't
  });
});
```

**HTML:**

```
<div class="dropdown clearfix">
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
   <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<br>
<div id="click">Click to toggle</div>
```

And here is the working (not!) sample: http://bootply.com/61988

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Just stop the event from propagating and it should work.

```
$(function(){
  //$(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown('toggle'); // this works
  $('#click').click(function(e){
      e.stopPropagation();
    $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown('toggle');// this doesn't
  });
});
```

#### [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7jkNc/)

#### [Bootply](http://bootply.com/61995)

Comment: Worked like a charm! Although my real situation was a lot more complicated than that, your answer helped me out.

Comment: It saves my time :) I was trying to fix this since last 1+ hour... Thanks by the way

Comment: After all the other answers I tried, this one worked! Thank you sir!

Comment: This is the best answer, after a lot of time wasted in useless answers ! Thank you so much

Answer (score 0):

For the vue user here,. you can use this.

```
<div class="dropdown clearfix">
   <a class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown" href="#">Dropdown trigger</a>
   <ul id="dropdown" class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="dropdownMenu">
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Action</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Another action</a></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Something else here</a></li>
      <li class="divider"></li>
      <li><a tabindex="-1" href="#">Separated link</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
<br>
<div @click.stop="toggleDropdown()">Click to toggle</div>
```

script

```
methods: {
   toggleDropdown(){
       $(".dropdown-toggle").dropdown('toggle');
   }
}
```